# What's the relation between arduino standard library and esp8266 library?

Tags: esp8266

Can I only use the Arduino standard library, without touching any esp8266 related header files?

I tried to connect to WiFi , succeeded with `ESP8266WiFi.h` header, but failed with  Arduino library `WiFi.h`.

I follow this https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ConnectWithWPA WiFi connecting tutorial but the board seems to reboot repeatly (I don't understand the error of course. I know nothing about hardware).

My board is `ESP8266 V3 ESP-12N F NodeMcu Lua CP2102`

Comment: the ESP8266WiFi library is based on the Arduino WiFi library so there are very similar functions so code can be ported between different WiFi libraries for Arduino.

Comment: the ESP8266WiFi library has examples in IDE Examples menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WiFi shield](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-wifi-shield) and an [ESP8266 with any of several popular WiFi services firmwares](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678) are different pieces of hardware, each of which can provide WiFi services to another device connected to it, such as an Arduino Uno. Their interfaces are different, despite that they could be used to do similar jobs - offloading the WiFi communications from the Arduino - and the two libraries are written to drive each of them, respectively.

Comment: Ah I see. That official `WiFi.h` library is merely for the **Arduino WiFi shield** "extension" board.